# Best to download secrets during build, or assign global variables during invocation for cloud functions?

Tags: google-secret-manager

We are currently using GCS for our secrets but want to move to Google Secret Manager. We include gsutil copies in our build steps, but I like the idea of avoiding that step in local development and instead get the secrets from secret manager at invocation.

I'm concerned about cold start time increases. Does anyone do it this way, and if so how impactful is it to cold start times?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean? Do you want to bake the secret into the application?